# Laravel join two values from diffrent two array into one array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two array from two query. I want to join two array into one array. Example:

```
Array1

[
   {
       fakultas: "Ekonomi dan Bisnis"
   },
   {
       fakultas: "Hukum"
   }
]


Array2

[
   {
       jumlah_wisudawan: "55"
   },
   {
       jumlah_wisudawan: "17"
   }
]
```

How to join two array above into one array like this:

```
[
   {
       fakultas: "Ekonomi dan Bisnis",
       jumlah_wisudawan: "55"
   },
   {
       fakultas: "Hukum",
       jumlah_wisudawan: "17"
   }
]
```

Please help me, thanks before.

Comment: What's the actual structure of your data? The code supplied looks like JavaScript, not PHP. So are the nested elements `stdClass` instances, or arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You could use collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

```
$collection = collect($array1, $array2);
```

and if you want to get that array, you can do it like this:

```
$collection->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `array_merge` not `array_combine`

`array_merge($array1, $array2);`

See documentation of PHP [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) vs. [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: True don't use array_combine I messed up on my answer!! But not sure that array_merge is the result he really wants :/

Comment: he can use also the function of Laravel `collect()`

Comment: Or doing it with a nice old foreach loop :)